# problem with submersion

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions, manifolds

Given $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is $C^{
k}$ class. If there $a\in \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ with $\varphi^{\prime}(a)$ is surjective.

Then there a mergullo $f:V\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ of $C^{\infty}$ class  ($V\subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$) such that $\varphi \circ f:V\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is mergullo.

Note: $f:V\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ is mergullo if

. f is homeomorphism between $V$ and $f(V)$

. $f^{\prime}(x):\mathbb{R}^{m}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ is injective for all $x\in V$

Appreciate any suggestion